# Environment variables in openshift

Tags: environment-variables, openshift, redhat

I am new to the openshift platform. I am working currently with an Angular project to be deployed to an openshift container. But I am not sure how to inject the environment variables available in that container to my frontend. I tried googling around, but the only thing I could find was how to manage EnvVar and not how to actually inject them in fx an angular project.

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, you need to know how to set environment variables for the container? Or you need to know how to use them in Angular?

Comment: Sorry if the question is a little unclear, I have already set up the environment variables in openshift. But I am not sure how to access them in the angular project.

Comment: Some quick googling doesn't really give a good answer. But this isn't an OpenShift issue, this is an Angular issue. Everything I found online talks about using a .env file and reading from that, not about reading operating system environment variables. Not being familiar with Angular, I can't really help, but I wish you the best of luck!